# status bar color not change in webview flutter without appbar

Tags: flutter, flutterwebviewplugin

without bottom overlay style check status bar color

[image: without bottom overlay style]

with bottom overlay style check now statusbar

[image]

the top statusbar of webview hides behind it if i don't use bottom overlay and color also changes from transparent to blue, but when i use bottom overlay it changes position bottom to statusbar but also changes color black even i set blue.

I am using flutter webview in my dart file in this file after using web view without app bar screen goes behind the status bar which is not good so I set it under the status bar which creates another issue to change transparent color to black.

here is my code

```
  @override
  void initState() {
// TODO: implement initState
  setState(() {

  //after status bar set bottom this color not change 

 SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle( 
    statusBarColor: Colors.blue,
 ),
);
 // for set webview under the status bar
SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays(<SystemUiOverlay>[
  SystemUiOverlay.bottom,],
);
});
super.initState();
 }
```

here is webview implementation

```
   WebviewScaffold(
        useWideViewPort: false,
          url: "https://www.google.com",
          withJavascript: true,
          initialChild: Container(
            color: Colors.redAccent,
            child: const Center(
              child: Text('Waiting.....'),
            ),
          )),
```

Comment: So you want your Status bar to be black and your webview to only be below the statusbar, right ?

Comment: @NisanthReddy i updated my question kindly look into it

Comment: Did you ever figure out a solution to this @Adnanhaider?